# Is the following flowchart correct for the given code?

Tags: java, flowchart

I have designed a flowchart that is based on this code in Java.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    attendance_and_student_management object = new attendance_and_student_management();
    int flag = 1;
    do {
        {
            int var = object.menu();
            if (var == 1) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                object.add_student();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (var == 2) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                object.search_student();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (var == 3) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                object.change_student_information();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (var == 4) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                object.take_attendance();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (var == 5) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                object.attendance_summary();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (var == 6) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                object.monthly_defaulter_list();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (var == 7) {
                System.out.println("\f");
                System.out.println("THANK YOU FOR USING THE PROGRAM!!");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("\f");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Invalid Input. Would you like to try again? Press 1 for Yes");
                int choice1 = Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
                if (choice1 == 1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
            flag = Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
            if (flag != 1) {
                System.out.println("Are you sure you want to exit? Press 1 for Yes");
                int flag2 = Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
                if (flag2 == 1)
                    flag = 0;
                else
                    flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (flag == 1);
}
```

The flowchart is given below:

[image: FLOWCHART]

I am still learning how to construct flowcharts, therefore, I am not sure whether this diagram is correct. Any inputs or suggestions will be much appreciated.

PS: I tried to make the flow chart a bit simpler, please do tell if this is more appropriate than the previous one...

[image]

Comment: I'm astonished you've even trying. I haven't done a flowchart since 1979.

Comment: Your code isn't great either. You should certainly be using a `switch` here, rather than an `if-else` chain. Which would mean that you should adjust your code to match your flowchart, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition on the chart

> Is var equal to 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7?

ist not 100% right.

Your program works with `if` and `else if` conditions, which check each condition serial. You first check the 1, then the 2, then the 3 and so one...

Your chart shows this conditions as an All-In-One condition, what in java mean a `switch`).

So your chart should show these `if`'s more like this:

[image: If-Conditions]

Next, you dont need to draw the chart-boxes

> Execute Method

In your code, you can draw just one box for the action in a true if-condition (like my added image).

And finally, you should have only one "Exit / End" point on the chart. Each flow that stopps the program, should link to this End-Point.

Comment: Thank you for the illustrations. I now have a better idea about making flowcharts. Just had a quick question. What about my control variable, flag? Shouldn't I include it in the flowchart? Something like.. is flag==1----if  yes then continue.

Comment: Not really - flowchart should not show too much specific details (normally no variable names are visible in a flowchart). You can draw the action "Ask user for repetition" or just a condition "User wants repeat?".